# How to split NSImage into 4 parts, correctly

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

This problem is confused me several hours

I use NSImage to load a local png image like blew:

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

this picture contains all of the statuses of a button. and every status part has the same width and height. so I want to split the picture into 4 parts. the code list on the blew:

```
NSImage* img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSSize size = img.size;
size.width = size.width / 4;
NSRect rcRect;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    rcRect.origin.x = i*size.width;
    rcRect.origin.y = 0;
    rcRect.size.width = size.width;
    rcRect.size.height = size.height;

    NSImage *target = [[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:size];
    [target lockFocus];
    [img drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height) fromRect:rcRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
    [target unlockFocus];
    [self.m_arrImg addObject:target];
}
```

But, when I check out the img.size, I find the size is not equal the image. I googled the reason, and I know the size is dependent on the PPI. 
So, my question is, how could I do the slipt work correctly in this situation? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: size.width = size.width / 4?  And then rcRect.origin.x = i*size.width ?

Comment: @ElTomato There is 4 statuses in the picture. Normal, hot, press and disable, so I divide it by 4, is there anything wrong?

Comment: I really don't understand what the problem is, seems to work correctly for me. What is wrong with the output size exactly? Maybe having the image would also help make this more understandable.